# Stop process to get Killed in windows os?

Tags: c#, window

When I am starting new chrome process then windows os is creating a new process for that. My question is how I can get the id of that process or any way to stop that process?

Comment: [tasklist](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/tasklist)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use `using System.Diagnostics;` namespace and code are as follows.

```
IEnumerable<int> pids = Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome").Select(p => p.Id);

// do some stuff with PID if you want to kill them, do the following
        foreach (int pid in pids) {
            Process.GetProcessById(pid).Kill();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

But now my question is how to kill the same process that is created by me?

And bcoz OS is creating new process after killing my process I m unable to track new process id.

Can we say to os to do not kill my process? There is any way to do that?

Comment: Stil that can be accessed by its name as long as you are aware of its name. Process.GetProcessesByName("yourTaskName")

Comment: No, process id is getting changed. I want to kill same process not all.

Comment: You can use the OrderByDescending and the topmost id will be the one added last. Change the code as below.

 Process process = Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome").OrderByDescending(p => p.Id).First();
            Process.GetProcessById(process.Id).Kill();

Comment: But in this situation, if a user opens new tab then it will get closed not my process.

Comment: At which point you need to close you manually created process? Do you have a background thread which is listening to all the other processes?

Comment: No, I am not using any background process. In some events, I need to kill the previous process and restart the same process with passing another argument.